# Bash erases the output file before executing the command

Tags: python, bash, file-io

I have a python script that reads from a csv file and prints to stdout. It is necessary that the default output is to stdout, not directly to a file.
When I execute this script in bash, like so:

```
program.py > file.csv
```

where the output file.csv is the same that the python script is reading from, it fails. The reason is that bash apparently erases the file.csv before executing the python program.
How can I execute this in bash so that the file would be erased after the python program finishes executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something ugly like

```
program.py > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv file.csv
```

Comment: Wouldn't `program.py > tmp.py; mv tmp.py file.csv` be more appropriate in this case? Also, it would be better to not create more files than needed, because this is running on a SD card and I believe it shortens its lifespan.

Comment: @shrx -- It really depends on how you want to handle the case where `program.py` doesn't exit cleanly.  Personally, I wouldn't want to overwrite my input file unless I knew for a fact that the program successfully created another.

Comment: @shrx -- I don't see how you can neatly avoid the temporary file without modifying your python script to hold the results internally and then dump them (to a file, not stdout) just before exiting.

Comment: The SD card is probably distributing any writes across all available blocks (i.e., it isn't constantly using the same area of the card and leaving other areas untouched), so unless the card is being used for something like swap, it's not an issue. (And if it is being used for swap, your creation of a new file here and there is not a significant source of wear.)

Comment: Allright, I'm gonna accept this unless someone finds a better way.

Comment: While a collision with something else creating a temp file in this case may not be likely, adding the process ID to the file name is cheap insurance: `program.py > tmp-$$.csv && mv tmp-$$.csv file.csv`

Comment: @William -- Yeah.  I had actually thought about `a=${RANDOM}; program.py > tmp-$a.csv && mv tmp-$a.csv file.csv`